# Count the number of occurances of a specific char by awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep

I have a data like this, fixed number of characters in every line(8)

```
RYRYRYRR
YRRRRYRR
YYRRRRRY
RYYRRRRR
RRRRRRRY
RYRRRRRY
```

I need output count the number of "Y" and "R" separately as shown below..

```
RYRYRYRR 3 5
YRRRRYRR 2 6
YYRRRRRY 3 5
```

I've tried a script using grep as shown below..

grep -c 'Y'test.dat which is printing some number like 13

Comment: I've written at the bottom of the question. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{print $0, gsub("Y", "Y"), gsub("R", "R")}'
```

In awk, gsub returns the number of successful substitutions.

Comment: Your command was not working in my system...A shown below..
 2 62 YRRRRYRR
 3 53 YYRRRRRY
 2 64 RYYRRRRR

Comment: @VAR121: You won't find a nicer solution. Make sure you include the filename on the end.

Comment: @steve I am sure that I have given filename at the end of command.

Comment: @VAR121: What version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: @VAR121: Strange. It works for me using the same version of `awk`. Are you using cygwin or similar linux-like environment? Are you using the bash shell?

Comment: @steve I ma usingg bash shell

Comment: @VAR121 Your file appears to have windows carriage return. Do `dos2unix` filename and once the file has converted, run the command @rici have provided.